# How do I count specific characters/integers in a string in html?

Tags: html

I'm a beginner in html and new to coding as a whole -- I'm currently taking a class and I've been okay up to this point, but I'm having trouble with this specific assignment. We're supposed to create a program that can tell you how many integers are in a string. The user should be asked to input some numbers, for example "123123123", to which the output would tell the user "There are three 3s", essentially. I'm lost so anything helps!

Comment: That's definitely not possible with only HTML. You'll need a script for that (most likely JavaScript).

Comment: We did this same assignment in Python earlier this semester (its a hybrid intro to python, MySQL DB, and html/JS), but we just started the html/JS component so I'm a novice to both of those. In Python, we used a format such as: "for Number in InputString: if(Number!="0"): continue NumberZero+=1". This was then redone for 1-9.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you have to break it  to char array and then
Do sorting using for loop just like take distinct  value from that and make temp array and return the temp array length